# Can't find directory spark using putty

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I was trying to run a spark code on hdfs using putty.

```
spark-submit WorstMoviesSpark.py
```

But when I typed the code above, it returned an error:

```
python: can't open file '/home/maria_dev/WorstMoviesSpark.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

*edit: I was just being stupid. I loaded my code on local instead of hdp. useful answer though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have the required permissions on the code file to execute it via Spark.
run the following command
`hdfs dfs -chmod 777 WorstMoviesSpark.py` then in your spark-submit command mention the master as yarn when running the code as follows

`spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client /hdfs/path/to/WorstMoviesSpark.py`